# How to deal with shared placements on a leaderboard with discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots, typeerror

The error message says 'points' are undefined even tho I'm trying my best to define them to it.

I'm trying to make a leaderboard command in discord.js using data from mongoDB, and was successful doing it, but I also wanted to add an extra loop to check if some users share the same amount of points and to display that shared position on the leaderboard. I have tried to define the 'points' in the code multiple different ways but everytime I get the same error saying its' undefined.

This is a working code:

```
const {SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder} = require('discord.js');
const leaderboardModel = require('../../models/2023');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("seasonleaderboard")
        .setDescription("Shows the top 10 players on the leaderboard for current season")
        .setDMPermission(false),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const members = await leaderboardModel
            .find({})
            .sort({points: -1})
            .catch(err => console.log(err));

        let embed = new EmbedBuilder().setTitle("GVFL 2023 Leaderboard").setColor("Yellow");
        let leaderboard = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (members[i]) {
                const user = await interaction.client.users.fetch(members[i].userID);
                leaderboard += `${i + 1}. ${user.username} - ${members[i].points} points\n`;
            }
        }
        embed.setDescription(leaderboard);
        return await interaction.reply({embeds: [embed]});
    }
}
```

This is what I initially tried, but got TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'points'):

```
const {SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder} = require('discord.js');
const leaderboardModel = require('../../models/2023');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("seasonleaderboard")
        .setDescription("Shows the top 10 players on the leaderboard for current season")
        .setDMPermission(false),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const members = await leaderboardModel
            .find({})
            .sort({points: -1})
            .catch(err => console.log(err));

        let embed = new EmbedBuilder().setTitle("GVFL 2023 Leaderboard").setColor("Yellow");
        let leaderboard = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        //if (members[i]){
            if (members[i].points === members[i - 1].points) {
                const user = await interaction.client.users.fetch(members[i].userID);
                leaderboard += `Shared ${i}. ${user.username} - ${members[i].points} points\n`;
            }
            else {
                const user = await interaction.client.users.fetch(members[i].userID);
                leaderboard += `${i + 1}. ${user.username} - ${members[i].points} points\n`;
            }
        }
        embed.setDescription(leaderboard);
        return await interaction.reply({embeds: [embed]});
    }
}
//}
```

This is what I tried after that, same error:

I also tried to place the

```
        let points;
            if (members[i] && members[i].points) {
                points = members.points;
            } else {
                points = 0;
```

inside the for loop with no success.

```
const {SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder} = require('discord.js');
const leaderboardModel = require('../../models/2023');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("seasonleaderboard")
        .setDescription("Shows the top 10 players on the leaderboard for current season")
        .setDMPermission(false),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const members = await leaderboardModel
            .find({})
            .sort({points: -1})
            .catch(err => console.log(err));

        let embed = new EmbedBuilder().setTitle("GVFL 2023 Leaderboard").setColor("Yellow");
        let leaderboard = "";
        let points;
            if (members[i] && members[i].points) {
                points = members.points;
            } else {
                points = 0;
}
        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (members[i].points === members[i - 1].points) {
                const user = await interaction.client.users.fetch(members[i].userID);
                leaderboard += `Shared ${i}. ${user.username} - ${members[i].points} points\n`;
            }
            else {
                const user = await interaction.client.users.fetch(members[i].userID);
                leaderboard += `${i + 1}. ${user.username} - ${members[i].points} points\n`;
            }
        }
        embed.setDescription(leaderboard);
        return await interaction.reply({embeds: [embed]});
    }
}
```

I honestly have no clue how to implement this feature.

Comment: If `i` is `0`, `members[i - 1]` will be `undefined`

Comment: I did try members[i + 1] but got the same error